# Set start cursor in code window instead of speedbar

Tags: cursor, speedbar

I have sr-sppedbar always turned on, but whenever I start, I have to manually click the code window to switch the cursor from speedbar to the codes. How do I start emacs with cursor in the main window instead of sr-speedbar?

Update:
It works after adding (other-window 1) to start hook in init.el.

Comment: Emacs runs through `startup.el` which is hard-coded into the executable, and people often have desktop restore features, such as `desktop.el` activated.  Selecting the right window/buffer at start-up is always a trick, and this is why I created my own `startup.el` and build Emacs from source.  The easiest thing to do will be to place a line of code at the bottom of your `.emacs` file or add a function to the `emacs-startup-hook` that runs last in time.  Essentially, you want to use `(select-window WINDOW)` or simply `(other-window COUNT)`.

Comment: See also the function `get-buffer-window` to help obtain the value for the first argument in `select-window`.  Alternatively, you could modify `speedbar.el` and `sr-speedbar.el`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after adding (other-window 1) to start hook in init.el